# SNS Topic Subscription using application in Python

Tags: python, boto3, amazon-sns

I am trying to subscribe to a topic in sns. I did this by referring to the document https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sns.html#SNS.Client.subscribe and there is clearly an application Protocol mentioned in the doc. This is the error I am getting:

botocore.errorfactory.InvalidParameterException: An error occurred (InvalidParameter) when calling the Subscribe operation: Invalid parameter: Invalid protocol type: application

This is my python code:

```
sns_client = boto3.client(
    service_name="sns", aws_access_key_id=SNS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    aws_secret_access_key=SNS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    region_name=SNS_REGION_NAME, use_ssl=True)

response = sns_client.subscribe(
    TopicArn=topicarn,
    Protocol='application',
    Endpoint=endpoint,
    ReturnSubscriptionArn=True
)
```

Can Anyone please suggest what is wrong here?

Comment: When do you execute the code? Do you have the latest boto3 version?

Comment: Yeah, the boto3 version we are using is 1.24.58